# Pasting text into Emacs but preserving empty lines between paragraphs

Tags: copy-paste, paragraphs

When I copy text from another application and paste it into Emacs it removes all formatting including the empty lines between paragraphs. I would like to paste into Emacs and preserve the empty lines. I am running Debian 10. My version of Emacs is GNU Emacs 27.0.50. The behaviour is reproducible with emacs -Q. The specific application in question is Atril document viewer.

Comment: All newlines are preserved if I open 2* `emacs-26.3 -Q`, open the tutorial in one of them, copy it and paste it into the `*scratch*` buffer of the other. That indicates that there is way too little information in this question. Which operating system? Which Emacs version? Is the behavior reproduceable with `emacs -Q`? Which other application do you mean? I retract my close-vote as soon as the question contains that information.

Comment: What @Tobias said. Please provide a recipe to reproduce the problem, starting with `emacs -Q` (no init file).

Comment: @Drew I can reproduce the effect now with the info given in the question. Though I do not think that this is an Emacs problem. The pdf-Viewer Atril or also Xpdf does not copy the text object from the pdf file with the correct number of newlines and Emacs cannot guess what the correct number was. But, `pdftotext` converts the pdf with the correct number of newlines into a text file. So the info is actually there in the pdf.

Comment: BTW: Copy-paste from [pdf-tools](https://melpa.org/#/pdf-tools) does also not preserve the number of newlines. (That is my preferred pdf-viewer since it supports `occur` and regular expression search.)

Comment: @Tobias: So it sounds like `M-x report-emacs-bug` is maybe in order, to report an enhancement request / bug for `pdf-tools` (?).

Comment: Are the empty lines preserved if you paste into a different application? Given your description, it seems like the bug is in the application you're copying from.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because given the description, this seems to be a bug in the other application that Emacs has no chance of working around.

Comment: This is not a problem specific to one application such as pdf-tools or Atril document viewer. I have experienced this issue with multiple applications. How Emacs works in its intersection with other applications is an Emacs issue.